# How to store timestamp a JSON object?

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs

I am new to angular js.I Want to store timestamp in a JSON object on click of a button.Can anyone help me how to do this.

Thanks in advance

Comment: just do it :D    ...

Comment: Like [`Date.toJSON`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toJSON)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a very simple example: http://plnkr.co/edit/C4sgMK8mg4wZUhiXW58n

We use `ngClick` in the DOM to invoke a function that lives in our `controller`, and once this function fires, it creates a new Date object, and adds it to our `dates` array. The DOM is set up to display all items in the `dates` array:

***JavaScript**

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.dates = [];
  $scope.createNewDate = function() {
    $scope.dates.push(new Date());
  }
});
```

**HTML**

```
  <body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <button ng-click="createNewDate()">New Date</button>
    <button ng-click="dates=[]">Clear</button>
    <ul>
      <li ng-repeat="date in dates">{{date | date:'M/d/yy h:mm:ss:sss a'}}</li>
    </ul>
  </body>
```

Comment: Thanks Lux its worked for me